# Display an image in gazebo

Tags: ros, ar-pose, image, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I wanted to simulate in Gazebo a system using a known target and a camera to compute the pose of the camera itself. I will use the ar_pose package the problem is that I am not able to display the know target. I'have tried creating a mesh (with blender) of the target and apply it to an object but I am having big trouble. First I don't know how to handle the material, I tryed to point, in the urdf, at the material file created with blender but it doesn't work and if I use a standrad material (like "blue") it doesn't display anything.
Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28844/display-an-image-in-gazebo/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

one example might be a image material script defined as `material GazeboWorlds/Face` in the [materials script](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_worlds/Media/materials/scripts/gazebo_worlds.material) with corresponding [image](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_worlds/Media/materials/textures/face_texture.jpg) and the [gazebo model](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_worlds/objects/object105.model).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0